# Not receiving any results from subscription to Rx Observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have made a sample application using Reactive Extensions.

I am trying to get a continuously updated list of suggested words based on the contents of a text box. However, no results are ever sent to my observer.

What went wrong in my code?

```
var ts = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(textBox1, "TextChanged");

string dicWord = string.Empty;
var input = (from es in ts
             select ((TextBox)es.Sender).Text)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

input.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
     .Subscribe(x =>
     {
         label1.Text = x.ToString();
         dicWord = x.ToString();
     });

var pex = new ServiceReference1.DictServiceSoapClient("DictServiceSoap");
var match = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<string, string, string, DictionaryWord[]>
    ( pex.BeginMatchInDict, pex.EndMatchInDict );

var lookup = new Func<string, IObservable<DictionaryWord[]>>(
    word => match("wn", label1.Text, "prefix"));

var res = from term in input
          from words in lookup(term)
          select words;

using (res.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(words =>
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange((from word in words select word.Word).ToArray());
    }))
```

Comment: please explain the problem you see in more detail. Are you getting an exception on a line? Or how is it behaving differently than you expect?

Comment: Ho Soner, i am using one Dictonary web service which has method which takes value and return related words. i tried executing webservice in web browser and it is working fine. when i tried to do this with The Rx it is not working. i am not getting any error. it is working fine. i did this program from http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/codefest/DC2010T0100-Keynote-Rx-curing-your-asynchronous-programming-blues key note example

Comment: Cleaned it up to pass muster...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *using* block will dispose of your subscription immediately. Rx works fine ;-)

Comment: Well spotted, I totally missed that! (Must have been indentation-abuse induced blindness... :) ) +1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try following the same tutorial in the official Rx Hands on labs at http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/5/D/C5D669F9-01DF-4FAF-BBA9-29C096C462DB/Rx%20HOL%20.NET.pdf.

It was written in the Rx 1.0 timeframe, but you should be able to make it work in Rx 2.1 relatively painlessly, and hopefully it will fill in the gaps for you.

Comment: I'll leave this up because you'll probably find it useful anyway, but Lee's on the money.